# Hosting multiple angular apps using 1 S3 bucket and 1 CloudFront

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am planning host multiple angular apps in 1 AWS S3 bucket and 1 AWS CloudFront? Something like this.

**AWS S3 bucket**

- /app1
- /app2

**URL**

- example.com/app1
- example.com/app2

In AWS CloudFront, is it necessary to specify "Default root object"? For error pages handling, how can we setup such that if it is error code 403 coming from app1, response with /app1/error.html and if coming from app2 then response with /app2/error.html?

Comment: Why do you want them to be inside 1 S3 and 1 CF?

Comment: For maintenance and cost saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use CloudFront functions which will change request link as needed.
Here's a documentation link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-add-index.html